# Insert cells in empty Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to store some values in an empty Pandas Dataframe. Something like that :

```
      | col1  col2  col3
------------------------
row1  |  v1    v2    v3
row2  |  v4    v5    v6
row3  |  v7    v8    v9
```

I get cells from other sources `ex: (row2, col3, v6)` and I don't know in advance how many rows and how many columns I will have.

I tried to fill my DataFrame this way, but it's not working :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["col1"] = ""
df["col2"] = ""
df["col3"] = ""

df["col1"].loc["row1"] = "v1"
df["col2"].loc["row2"] = "v4"
df["col3"].loc["row3"] = "v9"
# ...
```

When I want to display DataFrame,

```
print(df)
```

it shows as an empty DataFrame.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []
```

Out of curiosity, I tried

```
print(df["col1"])
```

and I get :

```
row1    v1
row2    v4
row3    v7
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

And

```
print(df.loc["row1"])
```

returns a `KeyError` exception.

Well, I guess I have an index problem but I don't know how to address it and **I cannot use `df.set_index` after first insertion** since I have other constraints.

I tried this too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=("some_name",))
df.set_index("some_name", inplace=True)
```

but it failed too.

Any idea ? I think I just need to set an empty index before starting to insert data, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way you can add values using the [pd.loc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method:
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame()

```
df["col1"] = ""
df["col2"] = ""
df["col3"] = ""

df.loc["row1", "col1"] = "v1"
df.loc["row2", "col2"] = "v4"
df.loc["row3", "col3"] = "v9"
```

Producing the following output:

[image]

Comment: Oh, it was surprisingly easy ! I need to wait a few minutes before accepting the answer, but thank you!

Comment: Do you know why the original syntax does not work? :)

Comment: @Roelant, loc access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array. In the first attempt, a subset of the original data frame was selected with df["col1"], and then the .loc was applied. In other words, you were updating the outputted dataframe, not the original dataframe itself.